# C read from console and write to .txt file

Tags: c, file, console, edit

How do i read a text written in console and then put it in the text file until user gives a terminating word??
I have written this but the problem seems to be that when i type exit it does not stop.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
FILE *fp;
char sentence[80];


fp=fopen("c:\\users\\kostas\\desktop\\original.txt","w");


while(sentence!="exit")
{
    gets(sentence);
    fputs(sentence,fp);
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sentence` is a char array. `"exit"` is a string literal. The two will never be equal. Try using `strcmp`

Comment: Also `gets()` is a bad idea. From the manpage on my system: "Never  use  gets().   Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the data in advance how many characters gets() will read, and because gets() will continue to store characters past the end of
       the buffer, it is extremely dangerous to use.  It has been used to break computer security.  Use fgets() instead."

Comment: I was about to edit my other comment to mention `fgets`. But yes, `gets` is dangerous, so use `fgets(sentence, sizeof(sentence), stdin);` to get your input.

Comment: i seem to have done it, thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:-

```
while(sentence!="exit")
```

to

```
while (strcmp (sentence,"exit") != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines

```
#include <string.h>
char buffer[255];
```

Alter these

```
while(sentence!="exit")
{
    gets(sentence);
    fputs(sentence,fp);
}
```

to

```
while(strstr(gets(buffer),"exit") == NULL ) {
    fputs(sentence,fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate using safer `fgets()`

```
#include <string.h>
...
while((fgets(sentence, sizeof(sentence), stdin) != NULL) && 
    (strcmp(sentence, "exit\n") != 0)) {
  fputs(sentence,fp);
}
fclose(fp);  // Code is missing this
```

---

Note OP's `while(sentence!="exit")` may have trouble as I suspect the first time, The content of `sentence` is not defined.

Comment: even with do while the problem was the same. thank you anyway